# How can I prove a point is within a triangle, given three other points?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangulation

Could someone please explain the formula behind this, and then provide an example of how to do this? Basically I have 4 points, each with a longitude and latitude number. (They make a polygon quad, so a square or rectangle, in the shape of two triangles.) I then have a user's point. This is their location, also in the form of latitude and longitude coordinates. What is the process I need to determine if that point is INSIDE the square (or two triangles)?

For example, I may have four points:

> Point A: x = 5, y = 0
>
> Point B: x = 10, y = 0
>
> Point C: x = 4, y = 3
>
> Point D: x = 10, y = 3
>
> User Point Z:  x = 7, y = 2

If I were to draw this out on a graph, I can see that "Z" is clearly inside the polygon. However, how can I prove this with math, rather than relying on graph paper?

Thank you!

Comment: in case of a triangle, for instance, perhaps you could try showing that your given point is inside each of its angles. E.g. first take $\angle BAC$ and your point $D$. Show that $D$ is inside this angle by proving that $\angle DAB + \angle DAC = \angle BAC$ (vectors could be useful here...)

Answer (score 4):

You can express the position of the fourth point in [Barycentric Co-ordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system) by reference to the first three. If these are all positive the fourth point lies in the triangle defined by the first three. If one co-ordinate is zero, the fourth point lies on a side, and if two are zero, the fourth is at a vertex (ie one of the original points).

Comment: we can can express the position of the fourth point if we have a rectangle but the OP's example is not a rectangle.

Comment: @AmirNoori: Barycentric coordinates work with the vertices of a simplex, which is a triangle (not a rectangle) in two dimensions.  The OP's Question is a little confusing in that the subject line asks about a point inside a triangle, but then gives data about a point inside a quadrilateral (two triangles).

Answer (score 1):

This is the classical "point in polygon" problem. There are two ways to attack it -- one way is to use ray casting, and the other is to use winding numbers.

You'll find lots of other material if you search for "point in polygon". [Here is one link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon), and  [here is another one](http://erich.realtimerendering.com/ptinpoly/).

You can solve the point-in-polygon problem by repeatedly solving the point-in-triangle problem, but you have to do it carefully if the polygon is not convex. See the second link above for details.

Answer (score 0):

How come do you think that there are just 2 triangles? You can make 4 triangles out of 4 
points.

BTW -> this page will give you some hints: http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/pointinpoly/

Comment: The charitable interpretation is that the given quadrilateral can be decomposed into two triangles, so a question about whether a point is inside the quadrilateral amounts to a question about which of two triangles the point belongs to (if either).